# How to get current location in google map for web

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, google-maps

I am new to this API. I generated api key but I don't know how to implement google map.

I searched a lot but nothing is working for me. I need help in finding users or device current location.

I need to display google map in my website with pointing to the current location of the device using angularjs.

Can anyone please suggest me how to get current location in google map or any tutorial where can I get code.

Comment: Check this code this is exactly what you want: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/blob/master/testapp/map_with_current_position.html

Comment: And here is the demo of that code: https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/map_with_current_position.html

Answer (score 0):

to get the current position you need to take location from the navigator itself 
with simple html5 geolocation code

```
<p id="demo"></p>


var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

after getting this location pass it on the map, your current location will be displayed

Comment: For this do I need to use any external links

Comment: a navigator is a JS window object contains information about the visitor's browser that you will be accessing no need for any external link

Comment: see live example here https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Comment: I just copy pasted the above code and if I call that two function. What will be the position to be passed showPosition function

Comment: position.coords.latitude is lat and  position.coords.longitude is long value pass it where ever you want

Comment: I am getting latitude and longitude. Now where I need to pass that longitude and latitude to display google map

Comment: you wanted the value I helped in it but I don't know what you are building so can't help you should figure out by your self

Comment: I want to locate company location and user's device location. I have company's lat and long. I want to find user's lat, long andlocation date and time. and also need to do geofencing around company's location. If user is with in the fencing i need to enable a button.

Comment: Can you suggest for creating map view